# RegEx for matching specific words and ignoring new lines

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Full Text =

```
"
......
A= 
B= 12345 
....."
```

I want to get empty word "" between A= and line break.
and want to get "12345" between B= and line break.

How can I get words using regular expression?

```
(?<=A=)\s*(\S*)\s*
```

or

```
(?<=B=)\s*(\S*)\s*
```

But, it also brought the next line contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this pattern:

```
(?<=[A-Z]=)[ ]*(\S*)
```

This pattern avoids the problem of wrapping over to the next line by first only allowing spaces after the `A=` (or `B=` etc.).  This means that in the case of the `A=` line, which only has a newline character after it, the `[ ]*` would match zero times.  Second, for the content it only uses `(\S*)`, which also will not consume whitespace and wrap to the next line.

### Demo

Answer (score 4):

[This expression](https://regex101.com/r/ftd7eP/1) might do so, and we can certainly add more boundaries, if necessary:

```
^([A-B=]+\s)([0-9]+|)
```

We have two capturing groups that we can simply call them using `$1` and `$2`.

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression would work and we can visualize other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

Edit:

Then, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/pDT0YB/1) might help us to do so by creating 3 capturing groups:

```
^([A-Z]+)([=\s]+)([A-z0-9-]+)
```

[image]

#### Test for RegEx 1

```js
const regex = /^([A-B=]+\s)([0-9]+|)/gm;
const str = `"
......
A= 
B= 12345 
....."`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

#### Test for RegEx 2

```js
const regex = /^([A-Z]+)([=\s]+)([A-z0-9-]+)/gm;
const str = `ADFJE = 12313-asrn[5493]h`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Comment: actually, i want to get  "123d-a5srn[5493]h"
 
Full text = "
ADF3JE = 123d-a5srn[5493]h 
RFD2AE = 133sdn[1-3-93]h
"

Comment: Your visual explanations actually take away from the real content in your answer, IMHO.  I'd recommend removing them (you may assume that the reader has at least a basic working knowledge of regex).

Answer (score 1):

Another option instead of using a positive lookbehind is to use a capturing group:

```
^[A-Z]+[ ]*=[ ]*(\S*)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[A-Z]+` Match 1+ times A-Z
- `[ ]*=` Match 0+ times a space followed by `=`
- `[ ]*=` Match 0+ times a space
- `(\S)` Capture in a group matching 0+ times a non whitespace character (This will contain your value)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sEW2ST/1)

Comment: `(\S*)\s*` may still have the problem of wrapping over to the next line with Powershell.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are right due to the `\s`, thank you for pointing that out!. I have updated it.